# redraw a CALayer with a new frame swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, graphics

I have a UIView with a drawing on it that is composed of CALayers being created from a hardware device then me generating UIBezierPaths and added like so:

```
self.layer.addSublayer(currentLayer)
```

If my drawing is done after a device rotation, let's say, 90˚, the image is appropriate. However, after rotating back, the image is skewed and doesn't appear as it should. In essence, I want to redraw my CALayer with a new frame every time the device is rotated.

I've tried a few things, for starters, I tried rotating the UIView itself. Then I tried duplicating the layer that was being drawn on and rotating it, then removing all sublayers from my UIView and drawing the rotated layer, not working.

```
let layerZrotation = self.layer
self.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
if(doRotate == nil) { doRotate = 0}
layerZrotation.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(degree2radian(a:doRotate), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    self.layer.addSublayer(layerZrotation)
```

I expected a complete rotation when the phone is switched from portrait to landscape based on doRotate being set as follows:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        drawingViewTablet.doRotate = 90.0

       buttonsShowing.doRotate = 90.0

    } else {
        drawingViewTablet.doRotate = -90.0

        buttonsShowing.doRotate = -90.0 
    }
}
```